# Strange Scala 'Type mismatch' error for tuples

Tags: scala, generics, types, tuples, scala-generics

I have a function `map` which takes a `Parser` and a function defined as follows:

```
def map[T1, T2](parser: Parser[T1], func: T1 => T2): Parser[T2]
```

I've created a `Parser` object of type `[(Char, Char)]` and a function `(Char, Char) => String`.

```
val parser[(Char,Char)] = //...
val asString: (Char, Char) => String = (a: Char, b: Char) => a.toString + b.toString
```

And then I pass these two to the `map` function.

```
val mParser: Parser[String] = map(parser, asString)
```

I expect everything to work fine but I get a type mismatch error for `asString` argument saying

> Error:(26, 41) type mismatch;
>
> found   : (Char, Char) => String
>
> required: ((Char, Char)) => String
>
> map[(Char, Char), String](parser, asString)

I have tried to explicitly specify the types for `map` as `map[(Char, Char), String](parser, asString)` but that didn't help either.

The type `T1` here is the char tuple `(Char, Char)` and `T2` is a `String`. So, the function `(Char, Char) => String` is what's supposed to be the input but scala is expecting a different type.

What am I missing here? Why is it expecting `((Char, Char)) => String` instead of `(Char,Char) => String`?

I'm using Scala 2.12. Don't know if that is relevant in any way.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you try `map(parser -> asString)` ? [Here](http://nikolajlindberg.blogspot.com/2008/11/scala-map-method-expects-tuple-k-v.html) you can get more information about Map.

Comment: What is that? I''m not using a Hashmap. I'm talking about the `map` function I've defined.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type `(Char, Char) => String` corresponds to a function that takes two Char parameters and returns a String.

What you want is a function that takes a `Tuple2` and returns a String which is somehow different.

Its type should be `Tuple2[Char, Char] => String`. 
`Tuple2[Char, Char]` corresponds to the type shorthand `(Char, Char)` but I guess during function definition the compiler interprets the parentheses as if they are used to group the function parameters.

This is a known issue and it's being addressed in scala3.
https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/auto-parameter-tupling.html

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now. I should've figured that `(Char, Char)` is being interpreted as two arguments instead of a tuple. I did try adding parens around `((Char, Char))` but IntelliJ showed them as unnecessary parentheses and I removed them because of that. This could be somewhat confusing to relatively new people. I hope they'll fix it soon.

Comment: @DurgaSwaroop I had the same problem recently. You shouldn't trust intelliJ it errors very often.

Comment: @DurgaSwaroop Report it as a bug to IntelliJ (after checking for duplicates)?

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out, defining a function, that accepts a `Tuple2` rather than two parameters, gets a little tricky, and ugly-looking.

A nice way around that is to use `.tupled`:

```
 val asString: (Char, Char) => String = (a: Char, b: Char) => a.toString + b.toString
 val mParser: Parser[String] = map(parser, asString.tupled)
```

`FunctionN.tupled` converts a function accepting N arguments into an equivalent one taking a `TupleN`. 
This is a bit nicer than defining a tuple-taking function, because of the parenthesis quirks you ran into, and also, because you don't have to deconstruct the tuple in the body.

Comment: That's interesting. I don't think I've heard of that before. I think this would be more readable too.